# Get the text from any type of document

Tags: c#, c++, c, windows, winapi

Is there any way (Win32API or other) to get the text from any type of window? I can get the `HWND` of the active window, but calling sending a `WM_GETTEXT` message doesn't always give me the text (MS Word being a good example).
I am trying to make a universal spellchecker, where from any application, the user presses a hotkey combination and gets corrections to his text.
Is it different if I want the whole text, just selected text, or say the word where the cursor is?
I can accept answers in c, c++, or c# using libraries or the Win32API or anything else. If there is a solution, but only in some other programming language (not likely that this can be done only in Delphi and not c with the API, but whatever), I can probably manage that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not going to be able to do this without referencing application-specific APIs.  Different applications handle text differently.

In Notepad, for example, the text is just a string in a multiline text-box which the Windows API can retrieve.

Word, however, handles the text internally and renders the display as an image.  All the Windows API knows about is the bitmap rendered by Word.  There's no way for the Windows API to get at the ASCII/Unicode characters that make up the text.  For this you need to use Word's API.  Many other applications will present the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you take a look at the UI [Automation API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx), that's the best you will ever find, as it was designed for this kind of usage, and forget about raw low-level ole' Windows API :-)

I quote the intro:

> UI Automation provides programmatic
>   access to most user interface (UI)
>   elements on the desktop, enabling
>   assistive technology products such as
>   screen readers to provide information
>   about the UI to end users and to
>   manipulate the UI by means other than
>   standard input. UI Automation also
>   allows automated test scripts to
>   interact with the UI.

A goot start is to try the [UISpy tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms727247.aspx). It will help check the kind of information you will be able to find programmatically *before writing any code* which at least will ensure you don't waste your time.

It's not so easy to find, here is a link: http://andrewtokeley.net/archive/2009/09/15/uispy-ndash-download-it-here.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but after trying with UISpy I couldn't get the text, so I assume it won't help me.